# Using Enums with Code First & Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Just trying to confirm an impression: it seems enums in EF5 + Code First are only supported when declared within the same namespace as the classes using them as property types.

Can anyone confirm that? Couldn't find anything on the web for this...

Comment: EF5 and Code First should work. If they are not let me know. Full disclosure - there is a bug in this area but it is for enums defined in a separate assembly - http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/532

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relevant bug that was fixed earlier. 4.3 Beta 1 release notes say:

> Bug fix for `GetDatabaseValues`. In earlier releases this method would
>   fail if your entity classes and context were in different namespaces.
>   This issue is now fixed and the classes don’t need to be in the same
>   namespace to use GetDatabaseValues.

My guess is that `GetDatabaseValues` function is still buggy for this occasion (but that's just an educated guess). You may want to report this here: [ADO.NET team blog: EF5 Beta 1 Available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/29/ef4-3-1-and-ef5-beta-1-available-on-nuget.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not only do your enumerations have to be in the same namespace to be supported by EF5 Code First, they have to be in the same class file as your POCO Model.

Comment: This is incorrect.  I've been playing with EF5 Code First this week and my primary model has two properties that are Enums, both in separate files.