# Entity Framework 5 RTM Code First enum support broken: enums in other namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

This is about Entity Framework 5 RTM Code First.

When I map an entity having an existing enum I get this error:

> No corresponding object layer type could be found for the conceptual
>   type '[FULL ENUM TYPE NAME]'

Actually it looks for the whole enum in the same namespace of the `DbContext`.

Some other question ([Using Enums with Code First & Entity Framework 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769619/using-enums-with-code-first-entity-framework-5)) had an answer that pointed to some blog post where there's a how-to on how to get this working but it talks about Database-First/Model-First approach.

**How can I add an EDM enum type using Code-First approach?**

Comment: Can you share your model? There is a bug indeed as pointed by Lukas. It should be fixed shortly in EF6. In EF5 - depending on the model it may or may not show up. Would you be able to move to EF6 if the bug was fixed?

Comment: @Pawel Today's sunday and it's something in my work, but it has no secret: it's just an enumeration type, a property in the model with such type and I map it using *code first*: `blah.Property(e => e.EnumProperty)`. The enum type is in a different assembly than the `DbContext`. I believe it should be the so-called bug...

Comment: This is now fixed in EF6 - should show up in todays nightly build.

Comment: @Pawel The project where I'm using EF is a professional one. I mean that it would be a bad idea the use of a nightly build in a commercial product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid it isn't possible right now  - there is known bug in the EF5 http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/532, that is causing the mentioned error.

I was struggling with the similar problem and didn't find any elegant solution. I ended up with `int` column instead of enum column.

**Edit** (problematic model):

Core assembly:

```
public enum UserStatus { Approved, Disabled }

public interface IUser {
    public int ID { get; }
    public string Username { get; set;}
    public UserStatus Status { get; set;}
}
```

Users assembly:

```
public class User : IUser {
    public int ID { get; protected set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public UserStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @LukasKabrt I ended up with the same solution like you, but it's very sad.

Comment: @Pawel My model is simple - see my edited post. I believe the problem is caused by the fact, that UserStatus enum is defined in the different assmebly then the User entity. BTW thanks for information about EF6, I can't use nightly builds in this project, but I will check it out.